# Editable Combobox - Can be edited in one application but not in an other

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, combobox

I have a class library where a WPF-Window with editable comboboxes. If I start that window in an WPF test application it works totally fine.
But that Window is included in an winforms-application and there the comboboxes aren't editable anymore.

I can click in them and the cursor appears, but I can't type. The rest of the application works fine and selecting an Item via drop down is possible.

Has anybody an idea where the problem relies and how to fix it?

The code below shows how I start the view.

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new Module());

        var mainView = kernel.Get<View>();
        ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(mainView);
        mainView.Show();
```

Also I explicitly set ReadOnly to false. That did not solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: What details are there still necessary, beside my poor English. Sorry for that.

I have a WPF-Window and open it via ElementHost in a windowsform-application with the shown Code. The ElementHost should make inputs  usable, but I still can't type. In the WPF-Application are diverse windows with comboboxes that are not functioning. I don't know what information is missing? View is the Class of the window. Including the window in a Wpf-application causes no problem.